# Mininize and maximize Buttons in Panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My Requiremet is
 when i Click on first button ,"my panel should me me mininised and must be stored in footer part of page and when i click my panel on footer then it need to take the postion back.
I am trying to solve this issue from many days, but getting stucked  somewhere the other, i am very new to these Things , please can any 1 let me over come through this

Comment: You're markup is wrong. You have ids appearing more than once on a page. Use classes.

Comment: Already Classes are there in same line, so i used div tag,

Comment: you can only have one id per page, you have four for each of the buttons.

Comment: I want this functionality for all the panels, so i have done so,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're quite getting what im saying regarding the ID, so please read this - http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php.

In other news i have a starting block for you - http://jsfiddle.net/Nghgp

It makes use of `animate()`

Note that in this example i have removed the ID and added them as a class.

Alex

Comment: Thanks Alex, But when i click on minimize button it getting stored in footer , when i click on all the buttons , on fotter it getting over written?when i click on all the the panel button, it need to show on footer all the 4 ...Thank You Once Again

Comment: As i said, this is a start for you. Your question is very big. It would be beneficial for you to work on the example I've given, then try to work out the answers to you other questions yourself. You can't really expect to come on here and ask for the entire functionality to be done for you.